# Using $9$ digits, how many $5$ number sequences can be made without repeating any number other than one, but putting them in any order.

Tags: combinatorics

Using $9$ digits, how many $5$ number sequences can be made without repeating any number other than one, but putting them in any order.

You can only repeat $1$ number twice, for example $12345, 23534, 89573,  66534$, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to explain where you encountered the problem, what you have attempted, and where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your examples suggest that either you have five distinct digits or one number that can appear exactly twice.  However, your title does not preclude the possibility that the repeated number can appear more than twice.  For instance, are you excluding sequences such as $12333$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Count 1 twice, so the string of digits you get to pick from are
1123456789

Then do 10P5 which means you want every possible permutation of 5 digit numbers from these 10 digits. If you do 10P5 this is equal to 30240, so there are 30240 possible sequences you can make

Hope this helped!

Edit:
I thought you could only repeat 1 twice.
Assuming that each sequence contains 1 repeating digit (needs further clarification),
Instead the following is suitable:

$5P5 \cdot 9C4 \cdot 4C1 = 60480$

Explanation:
9C4 chooses 4 digits from your string of digits and orders them - there are 3024 possible combinations of 4-digit numbers.

4C1 selects one digit from the string of 4 that you are given and 5P5 permutates the number of patterns made by your final 5 chosen digits

Comment: Your answer does not make sense.  You seem to be assuming the only repeated number can be $1$, but the examples show that that is not the case.  Moreover, if a number is repeated, switching the positions of the repeated number does not produce an arrangement which is distinguishable from the given arrangement.

Comment: You write "Assuming that each sequence contains 1 repeating digit..." but there is no such assumption in the examples given by OP. In addition, there are other errors in the working..

Answer (score 1):

- **No digit repeats:** $\;P^9_5 = 15120$
- **Exactly one digit repeats:**
  *(Choose repeating digit)(Choose 3 other digits)(Permute)*
  $=\;\dbinom91\dbinom83\dfrac{5!}{2!} = 30240$

Add up to get answer of $\;\fbox{45360}$